# Connect two separate project through Celery

Tags: python, redis, celery, django-celery

I have a project **"A"** (Django) where I want to produce messages to send to the Celery broker, for example **Redis**.

On another project **"B"** (plain python in the same machine) I want to launch a Celery server worker to monitor the messages in the broker and execute tasks. The tasks are defined in B.

When the tasks completes they will save the results in redis (also used as result backend).

When the responses are ready I want django to be aware.

Is this possible?
My main concern is that A should not import the tasks from B so I should use something like `send_task('task_name')`.

In practise I should create 2 separate celery instances but run only a server worker?

- instance 1 only send messages and read result
- instance 2 register tasks that will be executed. Tasks eventually send result to backend

Is this architecture correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

1. Is this possible?

   Everything that you are asking for is possible except:

   > When the responses are ready I want django to be aware.

   Celery responses are stored in redis, and django will not 
   be separately notified.  You are expected to poll the result 
   using `AsyncResult` to find out whether a task is done and 
   what its result was.
2. In practice you can run as many celery workers as you'd like. 
   The purpose of celery is to allow you to distribute your workload
   across as many servers and processes as you'd like.  For your
   architecture, yes, you only need to run (a minimum of) one celery 
   worker.

   In your producer (django) you instantiate your connection to the
   Celery broker using the following snippet:

   ```
   from celery.app import Celery
   app = Celery(broker_url='redis://....')
   app.send_task(...)
   ```

   In your consumer (celery) define the Celery instance as recommended 
   in the celery documentation.